# Elevated area around switch due to repair - need guidance matching texture?

Tags: drywall, texture

[image]I recently ripped and replaced a 2 gang switch so that I could run new wire down from a different fixture, and unfortunately my hole was much larger than the old work box I replaced the original with. To fill the gap, I used drywall paper tape and mud, leaving me with an elevated area around the switch. I'd like to match the wall texture to *hopefully* help conceal it, even a bit.

Question - can someone tell me what kind of texture this is? Looks like a form of knockdown, but not sure how to apply it?

I'm also open to other suggestions, even if that means cutting a larger hole :)
[image]

Comment: Yeah, you have to start by sanding that flat and filling the low spots.  It'll never look right if the surface isn't planar to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

This is creative free art. The artist is unknown.  First you want to sand that whole area smooth and try to cut down the elevation difference. You're going to have to practice this a bit but I've had pretty good luck using a wallpaper paste brush and dipping the brush into drywall mud and gently flinging it onto the wall. You can also dab it on the wall. Now you have the dimples. After it sets for a while, get your mud knife and make some sweeping strokes to flatten out some areas. This is going to take some practice so be patient. The good news is if you screw it up,just scrape off the mud and start over.

Comment: Thanks Jack. What type of sandpaper do you recommend? The elevation difference is also due to the tape under the mud so there will always be a bit of a 'bump', I suppose

Comment: A medium grit and wrap it around a 1x4 for a sanding block. The texturing will hide the slight elevation but you need to sand and feather the edging.

Comment: Since the OP _said_ thanks, but didn't _click_ thanks, I'll take care of that for him...